# How to code a retry logic in shell

Tags: shell, hadoop, scripting

I need to execute the command `result=$(elastic-mapreduce --jobflow $JOBFLOW --list)` and get the result back. I need to check in the result whether the string "PENDING" or "WAITING" or "RUNNING" is present and if present I need to retry the same command again , till I see no trace of "PENDING" , "WAITING" or "RUNNING"

How can I achieve that kind of functionality with a bash script.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would write:

```
shopt -s extglob
while :; do
    result=$(elastic-mapreduce --jobflow $JOBFLOW --list)
    [[ $result == +(*RUNNING*|*PENDING*|*WAITING*) ]] || break
    # do you need a delay here?
    sleep 10
done
echo "result now has no RUNNING or PENDING or WAITING"
```

The `:` command is a shell builtin that evaluates its arguments, if any, and simply returns a "true" status.
Read about the pattern matching here: http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Pattern-Matching